# Error al conectar Sql server con Web Application Core

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Tengo el siguiente error en mi conexión de sql server a Visual Studio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo en mi app.config es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQL_Connection"
         connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-ROTBMUO;
          Initial Catalog=johnsonControls;
          Persist Security Info=True
          User ID=DESKTOP-ROTBMUO\Macbook Pro;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

y el error que me marca en mi código es el siguiente:

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;
@{
    var db = Database.Open("SQL_Connection");
    var queryShow = "EXEC verLineasYAreas";
    foreach (var row in db.Query(queryShow)) {
        @row.nombre;
    }
}
```

No sé si tenga que instalar algún paquete con System.Data.SqlClient como lo hice con Web.Matrix, o si el problema esté en mi  o en mi foreach. Espero puedan ayudarme, saludos!

Comment: En la cadena de conexión le estás diciendo que utilice como proveedor `System.Data.SqlClient`, por lo que deberías incluir un `@using System.Data;`

Comment: Me sigue marcando el mismo error, de hecho al incluir esa linea me dice que el directorio es innecesario